# Getting Data from collection with mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want to take all data from a collection in MongoDB.
I have a schema that uses strict options as false.

What I tried :

```
const data = Myschema.find({});
```

Here, the data is the array of all documents inside my collection.

Currently, I have one document inside my collection so I tried `console.log(data[0])` and it prints my data correctly like this

```
{
_id: "123",
name: "ABC",
english: "weak"
}
```

When I tried printing `console.log(data[0]._id)` it printed id correctly too but when I tried `console.log(data[0].name)` it printed `undefined`

Comment: try ```const data =await  MyShema.find({})``` cause mongoose uses async for getting data from mongodb

Comment: Yep! tried that way but it isn`t working. It prints a complete object but if I try to print a specific item from it like a name it doesn`t get printed. The only thing it prints is _id rest all gives undefined